# Java: Get all Objects in Class

Tags: java, class, object

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class Items {
    String uselessText;
    public static final Item COW = new Item("text", 0);
    public static final Item CAT = new Item("abc", 1);
    public static final Item DOG= new Item("wow", 2);
        ...SO on

    public void search(String search) {
          for(every Item in this Class) {
              if(item.textString == "abc") {
                 //DO SOMETHING
              }
          }

        }
```

Is this possible? And no thanks I do not want to do an Array (because I have over 100 Item and I want them static access)

Any idea?

Cheers

Comment: one thing for sure..you need to change == to equals()

Comment: This has a horrible design smell ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can list all of the possible instances of the class at compile time, [use an `enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

```
public enum Items {

    COW("text", 0),
    CAT("abc", 1),
    DOG("wow", 2),
    // ...
    ;

    private final String textString;
    private final int number;

    private Item(String textString, int number) {
        this.textString = textString;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void search(String search) {
        for(Item : values()) {
            if("abc".equals(item.textString)) {
                //DO SOMETHING
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Much better approach that mine. +1

Comment: @VivinPaliath I don't know that it's _that_ much better - it depends on how else the OP uses the class. But thank you

Comment: I didn't notice that his class was called `Items`, so if he wants to maintain a static list of items, then an `enum` seems to make more sense here. :)

Comment: Great! But then I cannot access them by typing MyClass.COW am I rigth?

Comment: @AndroidXTr3meN false. You absolutely can access them, exactly like that. Sounds like you should read [the Java tutorial link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) I added.

Comment: Honestly I have never used Enum in my whole life :O I should do some reading :P But they are in a enum then you have to type MyClass.enumName.COW or?

Comment: @AndroidXTr3meN no. Like I already said: `Items.COW`. Try it in your real code and see.

Comment: I cannot name the Enum Items becuase my class is that name. Is Enum a whole different class because it just gives me error

Comment: @AndroidXTr3meN **change** the class to be an enum.

Comment: Thanks! So I have to type it twice?

Comment: @AndroidXTr3meN ...what? Type what twice? Why do you think you need to type anything twice? The code in my answer _should_ compile just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `List<Item>`? You could have the list be `static` although I'm not sure why you need it to be `static`.

Then you can do:

```
for(Item item : items) {
    if("abc".equals(item.getTextString())) {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Note that you cannot compare strings (or any object) using `==`; you have to use `.equals()`. For `String`, you can also use `.compareTo()`. When using `==`, you're simply comparing references. Also, use an accessor instead of making the `textString` property on `Item`, `public`.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array or a list. If you're concerned about hard-coding over 100 items, you're doing it wrong. Read them from a text file or something. But trying to use a new object instead of an array or list, when what you want is the functionality of an array or list, just doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not willing to use an array, or at least something that's iterable, then you'll make your work a ***lot*** harder than necessary.

For example, here is some code that will accomplish what you wish using an `ArrayList<String>`:

```
public class Items {
    ArrayList<Item> itemSet = new ArrayList<Item>();
    // Code to fill in itemSet - involves itemSet.add(new Item("text", 0)), etc.

    public void search(String search) {
        for(Item i: itemSet) { // Enhanced for-loop, iterates over objects
            if ("abc".equals(i.textString)) {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Having static access to those objects doesn't make sense.  If you want it back from this object, you can use an accessor that returns either the array or `ArrayList` to whatever needs it.